# Why are the cardinalities of these subsets not adding up to the universal set?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, permutations

Given a set of six letters $S$ = {A, B, C, D, E, F}, I am trying to find how many lists of four letters could be made that have exactly no repeated letters, exactly two repeated letters, exactly three repeated letters, and exactly four repeated letters.

The set of $6^4=1296$ possible lists in total represents the universal set of lists and has cardinality of $|S| = 1296$. Let $U$ = the universal set, and let $X_a$ represent the subsets of $U$ where $a$ is the number of repeated letters in the elements of the subset.  For example, ABCA $\in X_2$ and DAFE $\in X_0$.

By the addition principle, since $\bigcap_{a \in {\{0, 2,3,4\}}}X_a =\emptyset$, then $|\bigcup_{a \in \{0, 2, 3, 4\}}X_a|=|U|=1296$.  But this does not seem to be the case when I attempt to solve this problem.  Please let me know where I go wrong.

In order to find $|X_0|$, it is a permutations problem.  $6*5*4*3=360$, so there are $360$ lists of four letters with exactly no repeated letters.

$|X_2|$ and $|X_3|$ are where I am less confident in my method.

In order to find $|X_2|$, there are $4 \choose 2$ ways to choose two spots of the four possible in the list.  That means for any given spot in the list, there are $6$ letters that spot can be, but for another spot, but exactly one other spot must be that same letter.  So for any given choice of two spots in the list such as the first spot and the second spot, $6*1*5*4$ ways of arranging the letters for that specific choice of spots in the list.  Because of this, I believe that $|X_2|$ = ${4 \choose 2} * 6*5*4*1=720$.

In order to find $|X_3|$, there are $4 \choose 3$ ways to choose three spots of the four possible in the list.  I believe that the same logic as the previous step applies, where there are $6*1*1*5$ possible ways of choosing letters for each choice of three spots in the list.  Following this logic, there should be $|X_3|$ = ${4 \choose 3} * 6*5*1*1=120$.

Lastly, to find $|X_4|$, there are only six possible ways to arrange these letters where all four are the same:
AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, EEEE, and FFFF, so $|X_4|=6$.

After all of this $|X_0|+|X_2| + |X_3| + |X_4| = 360+720+120+6=1206$ which is $90$ off from what it should be.  Can someone please explain what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one more class of lists that you didn't count: lists with two different pairs of repeated letters, like AABB.  There are $\binom{4}{2}/2=3$ ways to split the places in the list into two pairs and then $6\cdot 5=30$ ways to assign different letters to each pair, so this accounts for the missing $90$.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  It seems so obvious but I can't believe I missed this for hours lol.